# get a zip entry as a pdf file and split it into images

Tags: java, pdf, zip, arrays

i have a file zip containing pdf files , so :

1. i **decompress** the zip file
2. i get the zip entry ( the pdf files )
3. i save each file ( **zip entry** in a database table ) as an array of
   bytes

this is the code to do that :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\manu\\Documents\\zipFile.zip");
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));//decompression

    ZipEntry entry;

    //int i=0
    while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        //check if the file is a directory 
        if(!entry.isDirectory()){

                println(entry.getName());
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int data = 0;
                while( ( data = zis.read() ) != - 1 )
                    {
                    output.write( data );
                    }

                    byte[] b  = output.toByteArray();

                    //--------------------save in database table invoice the document

                    byte[] pdf=b
                    String PDFName=entry.getName() 


                    def fact= new Fact( pdf:valpdf ,PDFName: PDFName)
                    fact.save()
                    //----------------------------------save in table Fact the document
                    // The ZipEntry is extracted in the output
                    println("saved successfully")

                    output.close();
           }

    }
    zis.close();
    fis.close();
```

the question is : i have to split the PDF files ( zip entries ) into images and save them as an array  byte in another database table this is the code i found

```
 FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = 
              new FileOutputStream("C:\\testing.pdf"); 
    fileOuputStream.write(b);
    fileOuputStream.close();
```

is there a way to do that without creating a physical file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your database , also what is the object Fact does.

if you want to store the pdf files into database,

1. Convert the pdf file ( zip entry ) into bytes
2. create column in database as blob
3. insert the values into blob column.

Note** , You dont need to create physical file

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19971334/2182351 -

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO testtable(stringcolumn, blobcolumn) VALUES(?,?)";
           PreparedStatement statement = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
           statement.setLong(1, version);
           ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b); // Here b is byte array from your sample code
           statement.setBlob(2, bais);          
           statement.execute();
           conn.commit();
```